# getting a JSON file from a list of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, json, list, class, enumerable

I'm new to C#, so please bear with me :)

I have a List of persons like this:

```
List<Person> PersonsList = new List<Person>();
```

each Person has three properties:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Number{ get; set; }
public Adress Adress { get; set; }
```

and I'm filling it from a text-file, now I need to change the list into a JSON file.

```
var list = Enumerable.Repeat(PersonsList , PersonsList.Count);
  var json =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

But I know it is not working because I'm not iterating over `PersonsList` in Enumerable.Repeat

Can you give me a way around plz?

Comment: Just `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PersonList)` is enough in your case.

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat` will give you an `IEnumerable<List<Person>>` where `List<Person>` is repeated `PersonsList.Count` times. Perhaps you just meant `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PersonsList)`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks to me like you are using Enumerable.Repeat() wrong. It takes one object, and duplicates it the amount of times specified. So you seem to have made PersonsList.Count number of new PersonsLists...

Is that the problem you are seeing?

Edit: 
As for a solution. I would just serialize the PersonsList directly. Unless there's something I misunderstood here.

Comment: this should have been the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you want to serialize the `PersonsList` to json again? Just use the

var jsonString = `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PersonsList);`

Answer (score 1):

**This is wrong.**

```
var list = Enumerable.Repeat(PersonsList , PersonsList.Count);
var json =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

You just have to do:

```
string jsonPersonsList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PersonsList);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

var List=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PersonsList );